# I want to connect to my ubuntu terminal using putty. I have installed putty already. How can I do it?

Tags: gnome-terminal, putty

I want to see the terminal using putty in my ubuntu machine. I have installed ubuntu and tried with 127.0.0.1 and the IP assigned by DHCP to my machine. But unable to connect. How can I do it?

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that you are trying to install Putty on a Windows machine in order to connect to your Ubuntu machine? Or are you really trying to install Putty on your Ubuntu machine?

Answer (score 1):

127.0,.0.1 is the loopback address, meaning the machine "talks to itself" You need to enter the address of the ubuntu machine you want to connect to. You can find out on your router, or from a terminal prompt (on the ubuntu machine) with `ifconfig` and look for an ip address near one of the interfaces (wlan0,eth0 etc..) (not interface lo)

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you have installed openssh server during ubuntu installation? If not you can install it like this from the terminal:
 `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install openssh-server`
And have a look at the ssh configuration guide: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Configuring

Answer (score 0):

What system you have?
If Ubuntu, use terminal (CTRL+ALT+T) put in windows 'ssh user@111.222.333.444' 
user - username in remote system
111.222.333.444 - ip addres remote host.